# Unable to create an object of the class from Maven type project

Tags: java, maven, nexus

My pom.xml has only 1 dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.shubham.TestNexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestNexus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a test jar that I have created and uploaded to my local nexus repository. I could see that when I am building the project, maven is downloading the jar and placing it in the Maven Dependencies directory. I could see the same jar added to the classpath as well.

This jar has nothing but a simple helloWorld printing method.

Now when I am using this jar in my project, it is not allowing me to create the object of the class inside this jar.

And, when I tried making a non-maven java project and added the jar manually to the classpath I am able to create the object of the class. Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Have you added mirror setting in maven pom.xml ?

Comment: In the Maven Dependencies of your project, can you see the jar?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the mirror setting in my pom.xml but I have the mirror setting in my settings.xml file. Also, I can see the jar in the maven dependencies of my project. In fact, when I ctrl+Click on the class I can navigate to it but the compiler throws the error -- Multiple markers at this line
 - <ClassName> cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - <ClassName> cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: I found the solution to the problem, seems like it doesn't allow the jars that have classes, present in the default package. I created another jar and put it inside a package and it worked. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Can we have multiple URLs for repository in the settings.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, seems like it doesn't allow the jars that have classes, present in the default package. I created another jar and put it inside a package and it worked. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I work with maven aswell. When i have problems with dependencies to try all this steps:

1. Use the maven clean and install commands.
2. Use the maven update project to force it.
3. Refresh all the project.

If it doesn't work the problem could be on m2 repo.

Comment: did you understand his question correctly? How are the above steps you mentioned going to help him ?